# How to select all the entries from the last month?

Tags: sql, mysql, database

I have a table with entries which has a DATE field. Each entry has a distinct date.
I'd like to select all the entries from the last month **registred in the database**. How?

I tried:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM registries 
 WHERE reg_date = DATE_FORMAT(MAX(reg_date), "%m")`
```

...without success

Comment: The last calendar month?  The immediate past 30 days?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on OMG Ponies' query with corrections:

```
SELECT 
  r.*
FROM 
  registries AS r
JOIN (
  SELECT 
    MAX(t.reg_date) AS max_date
  FROM 
    registries AS t) AS t 
ON DATE_FORMAT(t.max_date, '%Y-%m') = DATE_FORMAT(r.reg_date, '%Y-%m')
```

Though the performance of the query wouldn't be excellent, since it would operate the JOIN on two calculated values.
I believe it can still perform decently unless you start hitting millions of records.

On the other hand, you could probably run it faster by querying first for the MAX(reg_date)

```
SELECT 
  CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(MAX(r.reg_date), "%Y-%m"), '-01') AS first_day
FROM 
  registries AS r
```

And then injecting the result in a query:

```
SELECT 
  r.*
FROM 
  registries AS r
WHERE
  r.reg_date BETWEEN '<first_day>' AND LAST_DAY('<first_day>')
```

With first_day as a place holder for the previous' query result.
Provided you indexed reg_date, this should run pretty fast.

Note: LAST_DAY is a MySQL only function.

Answer (score 3):

If you wanted the last 30 days, this will work

```
SELECT * FROM `registries` 
 WHERE `reg_date` > DATE_SUB( NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY )
```

Answer (score 0):

This will give you all records for last month (May):

> SELECT [col,] DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP,
>   2010-05-01 00:00) dif1,
>   DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP, 2010-05-31 00:00)
>   dif2 FROM tablename HAVING dif1 >= 0
>   AND dif2 <= 0